# Sqlite3 location of database in Windows7

Tags: sqlite

Installing the .exe file in Windows of Sqlite3 (or rather the lack of installation) causes me to wonder where the database is actually stored for later usage? It does not output any file to the harddrive.

While using a GUI, it allows you to save a database as file, and later open it up in the command terminal for Sqlite3. But what confuses me is that Sqlite3 itself does not seem to store its data in the same way. So where is the data?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the database file as a parameter to the sqlite binary. If you don't do this, the database will be created in memory.

See the documentation about how to use the [Command Line Shell](https://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html).

**Edit:**

```
> sqlite3.exe database-file
sqlite> create table t (f integer);
sqlite> .exit
> dir database-file
```

Comment: I read through this a couple of times. I just cant find it. Maybe I am blind or something, but I cant seem to find "output to file".

Comment: This did not seem to output a database file. I am lost now.